# Mapping a function to a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Trying to map:

```
ff = f[x_, y_] := 
   Which[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, 1, 
    Abs[x] <= 1 && Abs[y] <= 1 && x^2 + y^2 > 1, 0, 
    Abs[x] > 1 || Abs[y] > 1, "Error"];
```

to a table of random coordinates:

```
Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 1}], 25000]
```

The code:`Map[ff[#] &, Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 1}], 25000]]`

But I get this:
[image]

Apologies if I'm missing something very basic here.

Comment: Try RandomReal[{-1,1},{2500,2}].  If you look at the structure when you construct RandomReal[{-1,1},{2,1}] you'll see that it is a list of individual elements instead of a list of a pair of elements.

Comment: And then if you define the random reals as "myRR", you can use ff@@#&/@myRR to perform the computation.

Comment: You probably also want to skip the first assignment and just go with f[x_,y_]:=

Comment: Try using MapThread instead of Map and Flatten your Table at level 2.

Comment: It's mandatory for me to use Map and 25,000 random coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

`RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 1}]` produces column pairs, i.e. `{{a}, {b}}`, which don't seem to fit your computation. What you probably need is `RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]`, which just produces pairs, `{a, b}`. So, a list of pairs of randoms is produced by `randPairList = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], 25000];`.

Now, with your definition of `f`, your computation is performed, as @Mark R said above, with:

```
Apply[f, #] & /@ randPairList
```

or the more Mathematica way `f @@ # & /@ randPairList`, which does look a little bit like censored swearing.

Comment: You should be able to simply use `f @@@ randPairList` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you have `{{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}}`, you can do

```
f @@@ {{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}}
(* {f[a, x], f[b, y], f[c, z]} *)
```

If you have `{a, b, c}`, `{x, y, z}`, you can do

```
MapThread[f, {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]
(* {f[a, x], f[b, y], f[c, z]} *)
```

If `f` is a `Listable` and vectorized function (i.e. one that works faster on lists than when called separately for each list element), use `f@Transpose[{{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}}]`. An example of such a function would be `Subtract`.

If you have the freedom to do so, and you are actually working with coordinates, it is often better to have `f[{x_,y_}] := ...` instead of `f[x_, y_] := ...`. One does not always have this freedom, of course.